# Manage network connections on Arch Linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I'm setting up an arch linux system(latest version) on my laptop. It already boots and configuration for network it's done via `systemctl`. Following instructions on the wiki I configured the ethernet service, first finding the service name with `ip link`, and then setting it up with `sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd@<servicename>.service`. But on reboot the name of the network device changed to `eth0`, so my configuration doesn't work.

Running

```
$ sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd@<old service>.service
```

(and all other systemctl commands aside list-units )throws error:

```
[...] Failed to create mount unit file /run/systemd/generator/-.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
```

How can I remove/disable the old config and set it up again?

Note: oddly my prompt changed to `[<username>@dhcppc0]`

Comment: Throws what error?

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules`?

Comment: @jasonwryan Nope, directory is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there was bug in the dhcpcd service, so it could work if you just do `systemctl enable dhcpcd.service`.